# satellite imagery data for crop identification

Tags: data-request, geospatial, images, agriculture

I'm working on a project to identify crop and do yield analysis using satellite imagery. can someone please guide me, where can i get this dataset?

Comment: what software are you using with that satellite imagery ?

Comment: I'm following  a mooc from coursera on GIS. Although, they are using arcGIS, I'm learning QGIS for the spatial data analysis.

Comment: I use ArcGIS but don't know how to do that in QGIS. I believe there is a support for that on their QGIS that you may look it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

USDA has a vast ecosystem that can be tapped into for this kind of imagery.

### [CropScape](https://nassgeodata.gmu.edu/CropScape/)

CropScape hosts a geospatial data product called the Cropland Data Layer (CDL). The CDL is a raster, geo-referenced, crop-specific land cover data layer created annually for the continental United States using moderate resolution satellite imagery and extensive agricultural ground truth. All historical CDL products are available for use and free for download through CropScape.
USDA FSA Satellite Imagery Resources (PDF)

### [VegScape](http://nassgeodata.gmu.edu/VegScape/)

VegScape delivers interactive vegetation indices so that web users can explore, visualize, query, and disseminate current vegetative cover maps and data without the need for specialized expertise, software, or high end computers. New satellite-based data are loaded on a weekly basis during the growing season. One can compare year-to-year change since the year 2000, compare conditions at a given times to mean, median and ratio vegetative cover, and can overlay a crop mask to help identify crop land versus non-crop land, among many functions. Vegetation indices, such as the NDVI (Normalized Difference Vegetation Index), and mean, median, and ratio comparisons to prior years have proven useful for assessing crop condition and identifying the land area impacted by floods, drought, major weather anomalies, and vulnerabilities of early/late season crops. The National Aeronautics Space Administration's MODIS satellite is used for this project and provides imaging at 250 meter (15 acres) per pixel resolution. Additionally, the data can be directly exported to Google Earth for mashups or delivered to other applications via web services.

### [National Agriculture Imagery Program (NAIP)](http://www.fsa.usda.gov/programs-and-services/aerial-photography/imagery-programs/naip-imagery/index)

NAIP acquires aerial imagery during the agricultural growing seasons in the continental U.S. A primary goal of the NAIP program is to make digital ortho photography available to governmental agencies and the public within a year of acquisition.

### More Resources

[USDA Census of Agriculture](https://www.agcensus.usda.gov/)
[NASS - National Agricultural Statistics Service](https://www.nass.usda.gov/)
[Aerial Photography - USDA Farm Service Agency](http://www.fsa.usda.gov/programs-and-services/aerial-photography/index)

#### Possibly Not Open (Noopen) Data

USDA FSA says "access is for subscribers only"; not sure if that requires payment (meaning its not open data) or not.
[Global Crop Production Analysis - USDA FAS Satellite Imagery Archive](http://www.pecad.fas.usda.gov/remote.htm)

#### Not Satellite Imagery, but Informative:

[Ag Census Web Maps](https://www.agcensus.usda.gov/Publications/2012/Online_Resources/Ag_Census_Web_Maps/)
[Details Regarding How the Ag Atlas, part of the Ag Census, Creates its Maps](https://www.agcensus.usda.gov/Publications/2012/Online_Resources/Ag_Atlas_Maps/index.php)
[NASS Data Visualization](https://www.nass.usda.gov/Data_Visualization/index.php)