# How do i collect mult temporal satelite imagery?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, data.gov, images

I am doing a project on change detection on remote sensory images over India.
I need images of the same place on two different time instances.
However i am only able to find images of certain place in a particular time (not selected by me).

Comment: Duplicate of https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/12833/satellite-labeled-image-datasets-for-multi-temporal-semantic-segmentation?

Comment: OK,that was my mistake(somehow i was unable to find similar question),however question is still unanswered.

Comment: Do you have any specific location you are looking for ?

Comment: Not necessarily , all i want is good data for change detection!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access multiple years of Landsat data here: https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov

Sentinel data can be found here: 
https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov
And this post explains how to access the data: 
https://gisgeography.com/how-to-download-sentinel-satellite-data/

Landsat has global coverage and decades of data, but you may want to be careful that the data you are accessing has the same satellite footprint / spatial resolution. The newest data, of higher ewsoluation, can be matched to the 30m resolution of older data by resampling the Imagery if you want to use a consistent spatial resolution.

Answer (score 3):

[Sentinel-2](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Observing_the_Earth/Copernicus/Sentinel-2/Changing_lands) provides repeat passes of most of the Earth's surface.

Answer (score 2):

If your location is within the United States, you can download imagery from the [National Map Viewer](https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/).

Comment: No, I am from India.

Comment: Please *edit* your question to include that information.